# Javascript regular expression to validate Facebook URL's

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook, url

I want a regular expression in javascript that can validate all the patterns of Facebook URL's.

I have tried some of the regular expressions but i am not satisfied with those regular expression's completely.

Also i want in regular expression is that,it should take/accept the facebook url's without:
http,https or www.

Means it should accept:

```
facebook.com/....
www.facebook.com/...
http://facebook.com/....
https://facebook.com/...
```

Please suggest me the regular expression that can validate all of the URL patterns of Facebook in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please include some of the patterns that you've tried already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hacked this very quick and it seems to cover your cases:

```
(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/?
```

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be good enough

```
/^(https?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}facebook\.com/
```